# Days left from two given dates php

Tags: php, date

I have two dates given, aug 27 2015 -> sep 9 2015. 
I'd like to know how much days have passed while using the UTC - 8 timezone.
Can anyone share a small tutorial/code to help my case? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Show us your code and where you are stuck, then we are happy to help

Comment: Okay, i'll update the post soon with my current code.

Comment: Please consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: Might I suggest searching for and reading about the DateTime object in PHP - it has a great many methods for dealing with dates, including periods of time between two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTime class also. And the [DateTime.diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function.

```
<?php
    $d1 = new DateTime();
    $d1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); //Do this for all 3 objects
    $d2 = new DateTime();

    $d3 = new DateTime();

    $d1->setDate(2015, 8, 27);
    $d2->setDate(2015, 9, 9);
    $gone = $d1->diff($d3);
    $left = $d2->diff($d3);
    echo "<br>";
    echo ($gone->format('%R%a days'))." gone. <br>";
    echo ($left->format('%R%a days'))." left. <br>";    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research and reading some php documentation comments, this code worked for me:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
    $date1 = strtotime("27 August 2015");
    $days = floor((time() - $date1)/86400);
    print("$days days have passed.\n");
?>
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as solved if it is so.